# How to place a specific character in front of a plain citation? e.g.: [1] is [P1], [2] could be [O2]

Tags: bibliographies

I want to make a distinction between peer-reviewed sources and other sources.
Therefore in my text I want to identify a peer-reviewed source with [Px] (where x is the original number referencing the bibliography entry), and any other source with [Ox].

At this moment I have a fairly default setup with a bibtex file (file.bib) and the following code:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{file}
```

Comment: apologies if this is a duplicate question, I did spent time searching for an answer, but none of the proposals I found worked for me :(.

Comment: As long as you don't provide any information about how you make your bibliography it is hard to help. Contrary to what apparently many people think, we do not have psychic powers and thus have to be told how your document look

Comment: Ok, I use a bibtex file, let's call it file.bib and currently have the following code to display it in my document:
`\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{file}`

does that suffice?

Comment: Always provide code. Update your question with this information. I don't think this is something you are going to get out of the box with any bibtex style.

Comment: I will update the question.
I realize that it won't work out of the box, but I don't want to constrain a solution by a given package. I am searching for any solution that achieves what I request, hence the "vanilla" code rather than multibib or other packages.

Comment: That is very simple with `biblatex`, but `biblatex` is a bit different from BibTeX and not compatible with `\bibliographystyle` (`.bst` files) (it may also not be accepted by publishers and can be a pain to submit to the arXiv), so before I write up a `biblatex` answer I'd like to know if that would be OK.

Comment: Hello @moewe, thanks! It will be used in my research preparation document and thesis so I assume that is not an issue. However, what would have to change? For instance, can I simply change the .bib extension to .bst, or is it a more intense process?

Comment: With `biblatex` you can still use your `.bib` file (very likely no changes will be needed, unless you hit one of the areas where `biblatex` or Biber is a bit less forgiving about errors than BibTeX; but some changes may be advisable if you want to use the full power of `biblatex`). The more relevant change is that you won't be able to continue using the style (`\bibliographystyle`) you are using at the moment. You will have to use a `biblatex` style. If you don't have a fixed idea/requirement of what your bibliography style needs to be like that probably won't be an issue, ...

Comment: ... but if you were given a `.bst` file you have to use or if you insist on the exact same output you are getting at the moment, you will quite probably have to invest a bit of time into modifying `biblatex` styles. (Some more background on '`biblatex` vs BibTeX': https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864)

Comment: It sounds like no issue, but just before you will invest in the answer, I have one possibly stupid question (being fairly inexperienced with advanced latex aspects). My university does have a documentclass that I am required to use. Could there be any conflict in that regard with your proposal? If not, then I am looking forward to your solution :D!

Comment: Yes, there could be an issue if the document class loads (BibTeX-based) bibliography or citation packages that are incompatible with `biblatex`.

Comment: It does have `\RequirePackage[sort&compress]{natbib}` in it, which according to your first source is an issue right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115680/discussion-between-danahi-and-moewe).